# How to Restore Gtk Widget's default color?

Tags: gtk

If i am setting GtkEventBox bg color to some custom color on some event like button click.

```
// Set Window Background color
GdkColor color;
gdk_color_parse("red", &color);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(GTK_WIDGET(myEvtBox), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```

and after another click i need to restore it to original state/color how to do this?
do i need to remember default color of that widget's state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might save yourself some time and get the answer faster if you read the docs more carefully. If you pass `NULL` instead of `&color` then you undo the effect of previous calls to `gtk_widget_modify_bg()`.

Comment: +1 for being right *and* trying to teach Pradeep how to fish!

Comment: Still I need to get the color as I want to apply the INSENSITIVE state style to non-editable entry in NORMAL style.

Answer (score 1):

As addition to `ptomato`'s answer:

in pyhton the value must be `None`,
for example:

`label.override_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,`**`None`**)